# Describing the relationship between catheter lumen occupancy and distal blood pressure in intracranial

Tags: blood-pressure, stroke, pressure

I am trying to characterize how the outer diameter (OD) of an aspiration catheter affects blood pressure at the face of a thrombus relative to the caliber of the vessel. In other words, how does the lumen occupancy, defined as

[image]

affect the blood pressure at the face of the thrombus.

[image]

I know it is going to be some form of the [Hagen–Poiseuille equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation), but even getting to the right equation has me out of my depth.

[image]

The impetus for all of this was to try to understand how the rapidly increasing diameters of aspiration catheters designed for stroke thrombectomy affect the blood pressure, and therefore pressure differential between the artery and the aspiration pump, as the catheters get closer to 1:1 in size. Obviously at 1:1 the catheter would be occlusive and the pressure would be essentially zero but how does 60% lumen occupancy vs 90% lumen occupancy effect the pressure.

Just given the r^4 term above I know the drop off will be exponential, but it would be really great if I could show it for specific values.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!